# What's the impact of using a GPU in the performance of serving a TensorFlow model?

Tags: tensorflow-serving, tensorflow

I trained a neural network using a GPU (1080 ti). The training speed on GPU is far better than using CPU.

Currently, I want to serve this model using TensorFlow Serving. I just interested to know if using GPU in the serving process has a same impact on performance?

Since the training apply on batches but inferencing (serving) uses asynchronous requests, do you suggest using GPU in serving a model using TensorFlow serving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to do a lot of tensor operations on the graph to predict something. So GPU still provides performance improvement for inference. Take a look at this [nvidia paper](https://www.nvidia.com/content/tegra/embedded-systems/pdf/jetson_tx1_whitepaper.pdf), they have not tested their stuff on TF, but it is still relevant:

> Our results show that GPUs provide state-of-the-art inference
>   performance and energy efficiency, making them the platform of choice
>   for anyone wanting to deploy a trained neural network in the field. In
>   particular, the Titan X delivers between 5.3 and 6.7 times higher
>   performance than the 16-core Xeon E5 CPU while achieving 3.6 to 4.4
>   times higher energy efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, you'll get roughly the same speedup for running on the GPU after training. With a few minor qualifications.

You're running 2 passes over the data in training, which all happens on the GPU, during the feedforward inference you're doing less work, so there will be more time spent transferring data to the GPU memory relative to computations than in training. This is probably a minor difference though. And you can now asynchronously load the GPU if that's an issue (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7679).

Whether you'll actually need a GPU to do inference depends on your workload. If your workload isn't overly demanding you might get away with using the CPU anyway, after all, the computation workload is less than half, per sample, so consider the number of requests per second you'll need to serve and test out whether you overload your CPU to achieve that. If you do, time to get the GPU out!